# Using libGdx desktop port as emulator of Android GLES20

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, emulation

My Android OpenGL-ES 2.0 project don't even run on Android emulator (GPU host) or virtual machines (Androidx86.iso + VirtualBox), but no problem with physical android devices.

so, can i use libGdx desktop port for emulation of Android GLES20 without integrating other libGdx stuff in my android project?
if yes, then how to load shaders from android's RAW folder without libGdx framework?!

beside libGdx, i find a working [wrapper](https://github.com/buggins/agles2wrapper)
but if i have to maintain a wrapper by myself, then NDK+GLUT isn't faster option?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that. It is what libgdx wiki says:

> Clearly there's no OpenGL ES implementation on the desktop useable via
>   Java. Well, there is now. Libgdx emulates OpenGL ES via the standard
>   OpenGL API on Windows and Linux. Nearly all features are supported
>   such as fixed point math and so on. The only feature missing at the
>   moment is support for fixed point vertex buffer objects and some minor
>   getter methods.

[Here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki) is tutorial how you can use libgdx with lwjgl backend.

[Here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson1#setup) is how shader programs are initialized.

You can see from the link above how shaders are loaded from resources.

[Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShaderProgram.java) is what ShaderProgram does under the hood.

You can see what it calls some functions of gl object which contains methods emulating opengl es 2.0.